# Passing tuples (key, value) into parameterized SQL query in Python

Tags: python, sql

**NOTE:** I am new to this community, so please let me know if I can help you help me!

I built a scraper in python that creates a tuple of (key, value).

I would like to pass both key and value as parameterized variables in an SQL query that updates a table in my sqlite database.

I have exhausted researching online and trial and error and hope you guys can help. Is this even possible?

**Example of what I want to achieve:**

```
    cur.execute(''' UPDATE Ads SET ?=?''', (tup.keys(),tup.values()))
```

**Columns in my SQLite3 database (identical to tuple.keys() ):**

Marke, Kilometerstand, Erstzulassung, Kraftstoffart, Leistung (PS), Getriebe

**Example of my tuple:**

{'Marke': 'Weitere Automarken', 'Kilometerstand': '88.888 km', 'Erstzulassung': 'Juli 1963', 'Kraftstoffart': 'Diesel', 'Leistung (PS)': '69 PS', 'Getriebe': 'Manuell'}

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you need a string to be executed that contains placeholders to accept the values contained within the tuple. Also, what you are calling your "tuple" is actually a Python dictionary, but that isn't a problem.

From the [**sqlite3 documentation**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html), we can see there are two ways to correctly use the [**`execute()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) method:

an example command is given as:

> ```
> # This is the qmark style:
> cur.execute("insert into people values (?, ?)", (who, age))
>
> # And this is the named style:
> cur.execute("select * from people where name_last=:who and age=:age", {"who": who, "age": age})
> ```

And the second example, the *named style* is exactly what would work with your situation. You can try the following, using the keys of the dictionary as the named placeholders:

```
cmd = """insert into YOUR_TABLE values Marke=:Marke, Kilometerstand=:Kilometerstand, Erstzulassung=:Erstzulassung, Kraftstoffart=:Kraftstoffart, "Leistung (PS)"=:"Leistung (PS)", Getriebe=:Getriebe"""
cur.execute(cmd, your_dictionary)
```

So each of the keys of your dictionary matches the name of the corresponding column in the target table.

Notice that I put the entire `cmd` in triple `"` to make a string literal that can itself contain the `"` character. I think it will be required, because you have a column name in your table that contains a space: `Leistung (PS)`.

Comment: Thanks for responding to my question! Unfortunately I wasn't able to get it to work despite trying exactly what you added above and a lot of trial and errros around that. I am going to go with the simpler solution of repeating sql commands for each possible variable (i.e. Marke, Kilometerstand, etc.). Just out of curiosity (and perhaps a stupid question) did this work for you when you tried this?

Comment: Yes, I have inserted things before *en-masse* in this way before. Actually I think I have also put all my data into a pandas `DataFrame` then used its [`to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method.